# Priority queue by variable

Tags: c++, queue

I'm trying to make a min priority queue in c++ , but the thing is it contains a struct as it's data and i don't know how to sort itslef by cirten value. Here's an example.

```
#include <queue>

struct data
{
    int x, y;
    float f;
    data(int x, int y, int f)
    {
        this->x = x, this->y = y, this->f = f;
    }
}

void main()
{
    priority_queue<data, vector<data>, greater<data> > open_set;
    open_set.push(data(1,2,4.0f));
    open_set.push(data(2,2,2.0f));
    open_set.push(data(8,4,1.0f));

    int y = open_set.top().y;
    int x = open_set.top().x;

}
```

I want the queue to sort itself according to the f value . This code dosent compile i cant make it run.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2676   binary '>': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   SFML    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xstddef 115

this is the error

Answer (score 1):

The compile error is because there is no greater-than operator for your `data` type. You are along the right lines because you defined your priority queue as `priority_queue<data, vector<data>, greater<data> >`.

You need to create your own comparison type:

```
class DataComparer 
{
    bool operator ()(const data& left, const data& right) const
    {
        // This might be wrong but you get the picture
        return left.f < right.f;
    }
};

priority_queue<data, vector<data>, DataComparer> open_set;
```